# Automatic in python

Tags: python, dictionary, finite-automata

I've been working on an automator in python, but I'm having some trouble creating a schematic.

If the input data is (where EV is even and OD is odd):

```
 EV|0|EV|1|OD
 OD|0|OD|1|EV
```

I'm trying to create a dictionary based schematic, such that for both even and odd, there are nested dictionaries

Though I'm having a lot of trouble coming up with ideas

Comment: Can you give some more indication as to what the final output would look like, for more data? Your outer dictionary can only have two elements in it, the way you've described.

Comment: @Symmitchry It won't be storing more data than that shown in the question! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
data = 'EV|0|EV|1|OD;OD|0|OD|1|EV'

# output: {even: {0:even, 1:odd}, odd: {0:odd, 1:even}}

information = data.split(';')
output = {}
for piece in information:  # Each piece is like EV|0|EV|1|OD
    parts = piece.split('|')
    head = parts[0]  # Our dictionary key, eg. [EV]
    tail = parts[1:]  # Stuff that makes up the inner dict, e.g. [0, EV, 1, OD]

    # Use step = 2 to get key:value pairs from tail:
    inner = {tail[i]: tail[i+1] for i in range(0, len(tail)-1, 2)}

    if head not in output:
        output[head] = inner
    else:
        # What do we do here?
        pass

print(output)
```

Yields: `{'EV': {'1': 'OD', '0': 'EV'}, 'OD': {'1': 'EV', '0': 'OD'}}`

If you wanted, at the very beginning, you could do:

```
data = data.replace('EV', 'even').replace('OD', 'odd')
```

Comment: Thank you SO much! This saved me a lot of time and effort, thank you so much :-) Worked like a charm!!